# How can I remove the delay for using react context in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-context, zustand

I'm trying to store some basic (non-sensitive) user info about the client, such as their display name and profile picture, in react context. The information is stored in localstorage so that it persists even if the client closes/reloads the page, and the context fetches the data from there, where it's displayed in a client component. Functionally, it works fine. However, I'm running into some problems:

1. In order to avoid a hydration mismatch error, I have to disable SSR for the whole component.
2. Even if I keep SSR enabled, the content takes much more time to hydrate than other client components, even if I build the app. This layout shift is really bugging me.

My question is, how can I make this info displayed immediately? I haven't seen anyone else running into this problem. If I'm storing it the wrong way, what would be the right way?

I've created a [minimum working example](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/auth-context-problem-svkjgg?file=%2Fapp%2FContext.tsx%3A35%2C24&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls9ngksh00073b6ha45iuh4a%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls9ngksh00023b6hmkw53t82%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls9ngksh00043b6hlgz0xec1%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls9ngksh00063b6ha5pz1e3f%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B49.53212582517462%252C50.46787417482538%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522cls9ngksh00023b6hmkw53t82%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls9ngksh00013b6h2szgsx08%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls9nu6tg00023b6hjlf895v9%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A35%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A24%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A35%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A24%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fapp%252FContext.tsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls9ngksh00023b6hmkw53t82%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cls9nu6tg00023b6hjlf895v9%2522%257D%252C%2522cls9ngksh00063b6ha5pz1e3f%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls9ngksh00053b6hre2m8tsx%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls9ngksh00063b6ha5pz1e3f%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cls9ngksh00053b6hre2m8tsx%2522%257D%252C%2522cls9ngksh00043b6hlgz0xec1%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls9ngksh00033b6hpwcxmkkd%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls9ngksh00043b6hlgz0xec1%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cls9ngksh00033b6hpwcxmkkd%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D) of the bug. I tried looking up all kinds of ways to use react context in nextjs, but none of them seem to suggest I'm doing anything wrong. I also tried to reverse-engineer [next-themes](https://github.com/pacocoursey/next-themes/blob/main/packages/next-themes/src/index.tsx) to figure out how it works there, but I couldn't quite understand it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

### Update

I have tried to figure out how I can get rid of this delay, but to no avail. I have generally accepted that it's just a consequence of using SSR, and server-rendered pages load even before client components can mount (though this time difference is less pronounced when in production mode). The way next-themes seems to avoid this is by simply preventing the page from being displayed until it detects the html tag and media query.

As a solution, I have implemented a skeleton component to avoid layout shift. I'm still open to solutions in case anyone knows how to make this information load instantly, but I have accepted that that might just not be possible.

### Update 2

I have added an attempt to use Zustand instead context on my codesandbox linked above. It has the same issue - there's still a brief period of time before the content loads. I want to know how users of Zustand counteract this problem. I still haven't found any examples that have successfully solved this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. As Yilmaz mentioned above, since the authentication is handled on the server, the key is to fetch that data in a server-side component such as `layout.tsx`. The key for stashing that data client-side, however, is to use a library like zustand, and create a client component that initializes the state as soon as it's loaded like so:

```
// storeInitializer.tsx
"use client";

import { useRef } from "react";

import { useStringStore } from "./useStringStore";

function StoreInitializer({ string }: { string: string }) {
  const initialized = useRef(false);
  if (!initialized.current) {
    useStringStore.setState({ string });
    initialized.current = true;
  }
  return null;
}

export default StoreInitializer;
```

```
// layout.tsx
...
  const data = await fetchApi();

  useStringStore.setState({ string: data });
  return (
    <html lang="en" suppressHydrationWarning>
      <body className={inter.className} style={{ height: "100vh" }}>
        <StoreInitializer string={data} />
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
...
```

By calling this initializer in `layout.tsx`, the api only gets called once, even if we navigate to a different page, and only fetches the api again on a refresh. We can access the data from the zustand store from any component.

I have updated my [example](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/auth-context-problem-svkjgg?file=%2Fapp%2FZustandTest2.tsx%3A10%2C1&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls9ngksh00073b6ha45iuh4a%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B75.55954982729497%252C24.440450172705027%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls9ngksh00023b6hmkw53t82%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls9ngksh00043b6hlgz0xec1%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls9ngksh00063b6ha5pz1e3f%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B61.674811971329255%252C38.325188028670745%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522cls9ngksh00023b6hmkw53t82%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls9ngksh00023b6hmkw53t82%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls9ngksh00013b6h2szgsx08%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsjg2xzz00023b6i26h9of3o%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A10%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A1%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A10%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A1%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fapp%252FZustandTest2.tsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsjg2xzz00023b6i26h9of3o%2522%257D%252C%2522cls9ngksh00063b6ha5pz1e3f%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls9ngksh00053b6hre2m8tsx%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls9ngksh00063b6ha5pz1e3f%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cls9ngksh00053b6hre2m8tsx%2522%257D%252C%2522cls9ngksh00043b6hlgz0xec1%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls9ngksh00033b6hpwcxmkkd%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls9ngksh00043b6hlgz0xec1%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cls9ngksh00033b6hpwcxmkkd%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D) to show the working implementation of this. More details on the implementation can be found in [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpMAH2hzKi8).

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to revolve around the `AuthContext` component and its interaction with server-side rendering in Next.js.

The problem arises because the `userData` value differs between the server and the client, leading to a hydration failure. This failure occurs because React API `hydrateRoot()` expects the rendered content to match the server-rendered HTML.

You can refer to the [React documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/client/hydrateRoot#hydrating-server-rendered-html) and the "pitfalls" section in the middle for more details. It's advised to avoid using checks like `typeof window !== 'undefined'` or accessing browser-only APIs like `localStorage` directly in your rendering logic, as it can cause mismatches between server and client snapshots.

Here's my workaround:

1. Initialize the `useState` hook with a default value of `null` to ensure consistent initial rendering.
2. Use the `useEffect` hook to update the `userData` after the component mounts.
3. Remove dynamic imports and directly import `ClientComponent`.
4. display something in clientComponent before update

Here's the modified `AuthContext` component:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState, Dispatch, SetStateAction } from "react";

export default function AuthContext({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<string | null>(null); // Initialize with null
  
  // update after component mount
  useEffect(() => {
    const userData = getUser();
    if(userData){
      setUser(userData);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ userData: user, setUserData: setUser }}>
      {children}
    </Context.Provider>
  );
}

export const useAuthContext = () => useContext(Context);

const getUser = () => {
  if(typeof window === 'undefined') return null; // Check for server-side rendering
  let user;
  try {
    user = localStorage.getItem("user");
    if (!user) {
      user = "I want this to be rendered instantly too!";
      localStorage.setItem("user", user);
      return user;
    }
  } catch (e) {}
  return user;
};
```

Using this approach may slow down hydration because components have to render twice. It can interfere with the user experience, especially on slow connections.

Also, avoid accessing browser-only APIs in render logic.
I hope this is useful to you.

Comment: Thank you, this definitely solves the hydration issue. However, it still takes a while to hydrate. I want this information to be immediately visible, like how one's profile picture is always visible instantly on most websites. Should I just store this data somewhere other than localstorage? Or is there I can make it load faster?

Comment: Yeah I suppose this could also be considered a trade-off with SSR, since ClientComponent has become dynamically rendered, there's a discrepancy with the static rendering of other components. One approach is to incorporate animations or bundle other static renderings into the rendering logic. Alternatively, you can try caching user data on the client side.

Comment: I am attempting to cache the data on the client side by storing it in localstorage. Is there a better way to cache it? For my next attempt I'll try using zustand and persist it that way, but I don't know if that'll make it any faster.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, how can I make this info displayed immediately?

you cannot do this if you store the user in localstorage because `localStorage` during the server rendering process is not possible. `localStorage` is a browser API and does not exist on the server.  In server-side rendering, next.js will generate HTML on the server and send it to the client. Hydration is the process where React attaches event listeners to the server-rendered HTML and makes it fully interactive. During this process, you should be assigning user as `null`, not authenticated. After hydration is completed, you can get the data from the `localStorage` and update the user.

If you want to show the user immediately, you should be handling authentication on the server.

> I do handle authentication on the server.

this is your `getUser` function:

```
const getUser = () => {
  if (isServer) return null;
  let user;
  try {
    user = localStorage.getItem("user");
    if (!user) {
      user = "I want this to be rendered instantly too!";
      localStorage.setItem("user", user);
      return user;
    }
  } catch (e) {}
  return user;
};
```

in above code if you have `if (isServer) return null;` how come you are handling authentication on the server?

Since it checks for isServer and avoids executing further in a server context, this code is not handling server-side authentication.

If your code execution has moved past the server check, it means it is running in a client-side environment.

Comment: I do handle authentication on the server. However, my problem is storing that information client side for persisting sessions and avoiding prop drilling. Basically, once I get my user info from the server, where should I put it?

Comment: update the answer to answer your comment

Comment: I have a separate backend that I didn't include in the example. the `if (isServer) return null` is to make sure next doesn't attempt to access localstorage on the server. However, you've made me realize that it would be best to call my api from the server-side page() component instead of waiting for the context to mount in order to do so. The only remaining aspect is where to store the data once I fetch it from the server. How can I make it globally available so I only have to make 1 api call per session instead of 1 per each request?